# Polymer numeric repeat template

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

i have a component which gets a list of  JSON Objects.

I want to do this: `{{i+1}}` in the output of the `<p>`-Tag it works(if `i=0` it displayes `1`)

However if I try this for the attribute `number` in the `<event-component>`, it doesn't work. The output is : `<event-component number= {{i+1}}>`

Any suggestions?

```
<template repeat="{{event, i in data}}">
        <p> {{i+1}} {{event.title}} </p> 
        <p> {{event.description}} </p> 
        <event-component number= '{{i+1}}' detail= 'false'></event-component>
    </template>
```

Comment: Would you show us a script where `data` is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somewhere in the code you did not provided. Let’s simplify the snippet:

```
<polymer-element name="my-polymer-el">
    <template>
      <template repeat="{{event,i in data}}">
        <p><em> {{i+1}} </em></p> 
        <p><b> {{event.name}} </b></p> 
      </template>
      <select>
        <template repeat="{{event,i in data}}">
          <option value="{{i+1}}"> {{i+1}} :: {{event.name}} </opion> 
        </template>
      </select>
    </template>  
    <script>
      Polymer({
        publish: { data: { value: [
          {name:'First'},
          {name:'Second'},
        ], reflect: true } }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

The output is as expected: `i+1` is calculated everywhere. You should double-check `event-component` code and/or your script.

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/ebEI0CptyBMOqtii86Vw?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your help! My fault was to access the number in another script via `this.attributes[i].value`, which returned `{{i+1}}`. Now I'm using  `{{number}}` and it returns the right value..